# Dual HTTP and HTTPS Python server based on BaseHTTPServer not working as expected

Tags: python, http, https, basehttpserver

I'm trying to implement a Python server supporting both HTTP and HTTPS based in BaseHTTPServer. This is my code:

```
server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer

# Configure servers
httpd = server_class(("0.0.0.0", 1044), MyHandler)
httpsd = server_class(("0.0.0.0", 11044), MyHandler)
httpsd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpsd.socket, keyfile="/tmp/localhost.key", certfile="/tmp/localhost.crt", server_side=True)

# Run the servers
try:
   httpd.serve_forever()
   httpsd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print("Closing the server...")

httpd.server_close()
httpsd.server_close()
```

So, HTTP runs in port 1044 and HTTPS runs in 11044. The MyHandler class is omitted for the sake of briefness.

Using that code, when I send requests to HTTP port (e.g. `curl http://localhost:1044/path`) it works. However, when I send requests to the HTTPS port (e.g. `curl -k https://localhost:11104/path`) the server never responses, i.e. the curl terminal gets hanged.

I have observed that if I comment the line starting the HTTP server (i.e. `httpd.server_forever()`) then the HTTPS server works,.i.e. `curl -k https://localhost:11104/path` works. Thus, I guess that I'm doing something wrong which is precluding not being able to set both servers at the same time.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe because of a typo for https? localhsot

Comment: There were a typo in my question post (now fixed) but in the actual test I used rightly "localhost". Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Um...Serve_forever handle one request at a time until shutdown, so if you want to serve http and https once at a time. Try to do them in different thread.

Comment: Thanks @M.Leung! Multithreading has been the key to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following feedback comments, I have refactored the code in a multithread way and now it works as expected.

```
def init_server(http):
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer

    if http:
        httpd = server_class(("0.0.0.0", 1044), MyHandler)
    else: # https
        httpd = server_class(("0.0.0.0", 11044), MyHandler)
        httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile="/tmp/localhost.key", certfile="/tmp/localhost.crt", server_side=True)

    httpd.serve_forever()
    httpd.server_close()


VERBOSE = "True"
thread.start_new_thread(init_server, (True, ))
thread.start_new_thread(init_server, (False, ))

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04  python 2.7      I use

try
  start_new_thread(http_server.serve_forever())
  start_new_thread(https_server.serve_forever())
  while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt
  print 'done'

which does not work out properly, 
as only the first thread seems to work i.e. "http://localhost:3000/"
wheras "https://localhost:3001/"
is blocking forever.
Can someone please give me a hint to solve this?

Comment: How can I add a code block to the comment correctly?
And why is the http / https protocol prefix stripped from the URLs?

Comment: Maybe comment is not the bets way for a code block... you could consider to edit your answer (using a EDIT mark and puting the new content below).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but editing is only allowed for 5 minutes!